# How to correctly set up internal ip for django-debug-toolbar

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

First time i'm editing `setting.py` file in `google` `cloud` `computing` please forgive me for this silly Question  ...

I wanted to run `django-debug-toolbar` and followed every step in that tutorial. And the thing i want is the tool bar to be visible in (`our` `office`) only.

So i just put our `public` `address` into `INTERNAL_IPS` like `INTERNAL_IPS = ('182.74.xx.xx',)` and i did `restart` run server. but the tool bar not visible. If changed back to 127.0.0.1 then tool bar visible again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's should work. Just `restart` and make sure recompile all the things. If production server running behind `nginx` make sure restart that too...

And if you want to check just replace your internal Ip address with different `Ip address` then confirm it.

Comment: restarting works ...! I don't know why first time it's not worked. !

Comment: Might be the case that you should restart Gunicorn or WSGI as well.