# Allow django-debug-toolbar to subnet

Tags: django

I can see toolbar from my pc. But I want to allow to all the subnet.

This is working:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('10.11.11.121','127.0.0.1','localhost')
```

Now I to allow want to 10.11.11.X

I tried without success:

```
INTERNAL_IPS = ('10.11.11.*','127.0.0.1','localhost')
INTERNAL_IPS = ('10.11.11.0/24','127.0.0.1','localhost')
INTERNAL_IPS = ('10.11.11.0','127.0.0.1','localhost')
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838400/how-to-correctly-set-up-internal-ip-for-django-debug-toolbar) question.

Comment: That's not working, it is only for one ip. I want all the range

Comment: Checkout [this](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1362/) snippet.

Comment: That is working.
Also in my case, allow for everyone : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10518040
As, all are internal pcs, restrictions are at firewall level.